# OpenCart PHP Custom Function Not Working

Tags: php, variables, opencart

I'm having a bit of difficulty including a custom php function in an opencart template. Here's what's going on.

In the header.tpl file, I'm inserting this code in the  portion:

```
<?php
$blah = file_get_contents("my_url_goes_here");
?>
<?php       
echo $blah;   
?>
```

Then in the footer.tpl file, I'm inserting this code:

```
<?php if(!isset($blah)) die; ?>
```

The purpose of this is to detect whether my blah function in the header is still there, and if it's not there to exit the script.

However, it seems the die function is throwing me for a loop, because if I move it up to the header.tpl file, so all the code is together, it works perfectly as designed.

But if I move it to the footer.tpl file, where I want it to go, it kills the script no matter what, and I end up with a blank page - even if the blah variable is intact in the header.tpl file.

This has got me pretty confused, and I can't figure out why it's not reading my variable if it's in a different file, as both of those files should be included on every page.

Thanks in advance for any thoughts!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are two separate entities, and as such data from one will not be in the other. I'm guessing this is some kind of detection script for reversed code like many do for wordpress templates. OpenCart is MVC based not linear and as such, $blah in the header is disregarded almost as soon as the code in it is completely executed

Comment: Jay - thanks for the post. You're sort of correct. Any way to get around this issue, like making the variable global?

Comment: You could do exactly that sure. Possibly even save the value into a session value so you don't have to call it with each page load which is going to be an overhead both your server and the client site won't want

Comment: Good idea. I'll try implementing that. Thanks!!

Comment: Jay - as far as saving that value into a session - how would that look?

Comment: I added $_SESSION['blah'] = "$blah"; after the first php function above, but my footer die code is still not reading it.

Comment: Firstly, you don't need the quotes around $blah, or in fact to even do it that way. You can just assign it directly. `$this->session->data['blah'] = file_get_contents('url');`. Then you check the value is set in the footer: `if(isset($this->session->data['blah'])) die();`

Comment: Jay - keep in mind, this is going inside of the header.tpl file - I need to try and keep all the code to inside the template files. Is this still something that will work? Can I define blah from inside the header.tpl?